# List of files through your path

Tags: php, jquery, foreach

good day I would like to ask or not to know any such scripts on php or jquery as in the picture.

[this is image file list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTGSK.png)

Data can only be selected through foreach in the format eg

> The walking dead / The walking dead S01 / The.Walking.Dead.S01E04.480p.mkv

so it's just a file path.

Excuse my English and thank you for the answers.

I tried this but it did not lead anywhere.

```
$str = 'THE WALKING DEAD/THE WALKING DEAD S01/The.Walking.Dead.S01E04.480p.BRRip.x264.AC3.CzDub-jDM.mkv';

$output = array();
$chunks = explode('/', $str);
foreach ($chunks as $i => $chunk) {
    echo $chunk.'<br>';
}
```

I've tried a lot of bosses and this is the last one I've ever tried.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: nothing, I do not know how to do it

Comment: This site is for specific programming questions, as it stands this question is too broad. Read up a few tutorials first .

Comment: A good practice will be if you try to do it. Don't get me wrong, we love helping people. But it is really important to test your curiosity and finding a way of solving problems. And when ever you are stock, your questions will surely be answered. See the [How to, Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I fixed my question. Please help me

Comment: You could've at least use another example, instead of showing the whole world that you download illegal copies of tv series

Comment: @AlonEitan it's only illegal without written consent from the creators and we can't know if OP has that ... or can we.

Comment: You could've at least used a different TV show? The walking dead is so boring.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/es/function.pathinfo.php):

```
$str = 'THE WALKING DEAD/THE WALKING DEAD S01/The.Walking.Dead.S01E04.480p.BRRip.x264.AC3.CzDub-jDM.mkv';
$a = var_dump(pathinfo($str));
```

That would give you:

```
array(4) {
  ["dirname"]=>
  string(37) "THE WALKING DEAD/THE WALKING DEAD S01"
  ["basename"]=>
  string(57) "The.Walking.Dead.S01E04.480p.BRRip.x264.AC3.CzDub-jDM.mkv"
  ["extension"]=>
  string(3) "mkv"
  ["filename"]=>
  string(53) "The.Walking.Dead.S01E04.480p.BRRip.x264.AC3.CzDub-jDM"
}
```

If you want only the dirname, you could use:

```
echo pathinfo($str, PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
```

Comment: this could be used but I still do not think how to use it as it is on the picture in which is in the main question